# Graphical properties of Dirichlet kernel

Tags: real-analysis

Dirichlet kernel is $D_n(x)=\sum \limits_{k=-n}^{n}e^{ikx}=\dfrac{\sin (n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}$. The last equality can be check very elementary. We know that $D_n(x)$ is odd function with period $2\pi$ and $D_n(0)=2n+1$. Also $D_n(x)$ has zeros at points $x_k=\frac{2\pi k}{2n+1}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Here's the graphs of some first $D_n(x)$ and we see that each graph has intervals of monotone increasing and decreasing. Also on any interval $(x_k,x_{k+1})$ $D_n(x)$ has absolute minimum or maximum (how to find these critical points?). Can anyone please explain these moments to me explicitly? I would be very greatful to anyone's help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A maximum is obtained whenever both numerator and the denominator vanish at the same time.

A minimum is achieved whenever the numerator vanishes and the denominator doesn't vanish.

You can read on this in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraunhofer_diffraction_(mathematics)

You should read it in any waves book.

Comment: You wrote that "A maximum is obtained whenever both numerator and the denominator vanish at the same time, A minimum is achieved whenever the numerator vanishes and the denominator doesn't vanish.." Why? Can you reveal your answer please?

Comment: I need to recall this myself. But if you look for minima and maxima you should take a derivative once to get: $(n+1/2)\cos((n+1/2)x)\sin(x/2) - \sin((n+1/2)x)1/2 \cos(x/2) = 0$. I am not sure this will lead to something meaningful. The heauristics from physics, which is where I first encountered DK we know that the max of this function is achieved whenever the denominator is zero, but if it's zero the expression won't be defined so we need to look for when also the numerator is zero. As for the minima if you were to rescale the function such that the minima would be on the x-axis i.e zero.

Comment: I encourage you to search for an explanation on the relative maxima and minima in any book on waves or trigonometric series.

Comment: What book for example? Because I'm beginner in this branch.

Comment: You can search for this in Pain's textbook: The Physics of waves and vibrations 5th edition. They are looking at the square of Dirichlet kernel on page 367 onwards.